# how to integrate spring 3.1.2 RELEASE in liferay 6.1 GA2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-6

I don't  know how to do it:
What i have to know about the context-application?
What about for dependency?

I use this for application-context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">



<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="viewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/">
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp">
 </property></property></property></bean>
 <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.web.portlet" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />

</beans>
```

I include spring 3.1.2 in my library and build path

I get error: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

Comment: Does this look correct to you? _</property></property></property>_

Comment: Thank you, I fix it, it's not from this.